# What does current method do?

Tags: javascript

What is the `current` chained method doing in this code snippet? The `slug` is either a string or undefined. The code snippet is in a Gatsby project. If there's a definition for the method, I'm having trouble finding it since "current" as a search keyword pulls up a large number of results.

```
return (slug || {}).current
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `slug` is either a string or `undefined`? Because strings don't natively have a `current` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns the `current` property of `slug` if the parameter exists.

Otherwise it returns `undefined`.

---

```
(slug || {}).current
```

If the `slug` parameter is not present, slug returns `false` and result of the expression is `{}` (since `{}` returns true). Since no current property exists, `undefined` is returned

If the `slug` parameter is present, the result of expression is `slug` since `slug` returns `true` and the [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) short circuits while evaluating left to right. Thus, the `current` property of `slug` is returned.

---

Short circuit means that the `{}` part is not evaluated, hence any side effects of doing so do not take effect (e.g., if `{}` is a function call, the calling never takes place). This happens because the value of the operator is already determined after the evaluation of the first operand.<sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Spectric - is my assumption that current is a built-in Javascript property correct? I couldn't find it on MDN's site.

Comment: @webstackdev It's not built-in. It's just a property of an object. E.g, I could declare an object with the `current` property like this: `{current: 'somevalue'}`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is very similar to a ternary operator, it'll check for truthy value on the left side (for you `slug`) and if it's false then it'll use the value from the right side:

```js
<truthy?> || <replacement>
```

Or in other words, if the value `slug` exists, it'll use it and then `current` attribute is accessed. If `slug` doesn't exist, an empty `Object` is used instead - for the attribute access, the first dot.

Such an object (`{}`) doesn't have an attribute `current`, therefore either you'll end up with `slug.current` (which may be whatever) or `undefined` (`{}.current`) as a replacement, so it doesn't fail on commonly undefined dot-access:

```js
const slug = undefined;
slug.current;  // boom
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: slug is undefined
```

It's commonly used for chained dot-access such as:

```
((mayBeUndefined || {}).objMightBeMissing || {}).someAttrIWant
```